# How do I center a navbar styled in scss without messing up subnav alignment?

Tags: html, css, sass

I found an example of a nav menu online that matches my needs and is styled in Sass (or scss), but having a little trouble.

(NOTE: I managed to answer this myself while fiddling with this for posting, however I don't really understand why it worked. If I could get an answer explaining that, perhaps.)

I have a nav element with a ul child, and some of the li have a ul (i.e. some links have subnav menus). I am trying to center the navbar, but whatever styling I add to do so ends up changing the subnav menus, which will being to appear about 100 px to the right of the nav link above.

```
    <li>
        <a href="#">The Journey</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="finding.html">Finding your way home</a></li>
            <li><a href="confusion.html">Confusion is normal</a></li>
            <li><a href="mistakes.html">Mistakes are okay</a></li>
            <li><a href="fiddling.html">Fiddling is fine</a></li>
            <li><a href="navigating.html">Become a navigator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">The Power</a>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 4</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</nav>
```

styling, in scss:

```
nav {
  /* tried two versions of the following. */
  /* version 1, in which the navbar is centered, but the subnav */
  /* menus are shifted about 100px to the right,: the following */
  /* line is present. */
  /* it is absent in version 2, in which the */
  /* navbar is not centered but the subnav menus are lined up  */
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  /* in version 1 only, the following line is present */
  display: inline-block;

  list-style:none;

  li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    a {
     display:block;
     padding: $link-vertical-padding $link-horizontal-padding;
     text-align:center;
     color:$link-color;
     text-decoration:none;
     transition: all 0.1s ease;

    &:hover {
      background: $color-bg-nav-hover;
      color:$link-hover;
      transition: all 0.2s ease;
    }

    ul {
      background:  $color-bg-subnav;
      list-style:none;
      padding:0;
      position:absolute;
      width:200px;
      max-height:0;
      z-index:0;
      opacity:0;
      overflow:hidden;
      font-size:.9em;
      box-shadow:0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      transition: all 0.3s ease;


      li {
        float:none;
        margin:0;


        a {
                color: #FFFFFF;
          display:block;
          text-align:left;
          padding:$link-vertical-padding/1.5 $link-horizontal-padding/1.5;
          margin:0;
          border-right:none;
          border-top:1px solid darken($menu-background,12%);;
          box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.03);
          text-transform:none;
          text-shadow:none;
          transition: all 0.2s ease;

          &:hover {
            color:$link-hover;
            background:lighten($menu-background,5%);
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
          }

        }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is what I figured out while constructing this question:

It does work, when the goal is to center the navbar, to add this line to the nav  and 'nav ul' styling:

```
nav {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
....
}
```

However, this also applies 'inline-block' display mode to the 'li', 'a', and subnav 'ul' elements, which affects the subnav alignment. The solution is to make sure 'inline-block' is only applied to the 'ul' which is a direct descendent of 'nav':

```
nav > ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul {
  .. the remainder of styling posted in question ..;
}
```

At this point, my question would be "Which element shouldn't have 'inline-block' styling, and is there another way to avoid that?"

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `flexbox` in `nav`, it's much more easier than other solutions:

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```